# Bind datagrid column visibility to a dictionary value

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, dictionary, datagrid

people! I have an issue:
i have an app on MVVM Light with DataGrid:

```
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyCollection, Mode=TwoWay}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False"
                        FontSize="14" Name="ItemGrid" SelectionUnit="FullRow" ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource ResourceKey=DataGridColumnHeader}" Background="Transparent"
                   Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}},UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" 
                        CanUserResizeRows="False" SelectionMode="Single" BorderThickness="0">
                    <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <DataGrid
                                IsReadOnly="True"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}"
                                SelectionUnit="FullRow"
                                Visibility="{Binding Path=DataContext.RowDetailsVisibility, Mode=TwoWay,Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
                                CanUserResizeRows="False"
                                CanUserResizeColumns="True"
                                SelectedItem="{Binding Path=DataContext.SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}">
                                <DataGrid.Columns>
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Visibility="Collapsed" Binding="{Binding ID}" Width="Auto" CellStyle="{StaticResource ResourceKey=DataGridCell}" />
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Title" Visibility="Visible" Binding="{Binding Title}" Width="Auto" CellStyle="{StaticResource ResourceKey=DataGridCell}" />
                                </DataGrid.Columns>
                            </DataGrid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Item Pack ID" Width="*" CellStyle="{StaticResource ResourceKey=DataGridCell}">
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Id, Mode=TwoWay}" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=TextBoxStyle}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                       <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Number" Width="*" CellStyle="{StaticResource ResourceKey=DataGridCell}">
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Number, Mode=TwoWay}" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=TextBoxStyle}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
     </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu Name="contextMenu" Style="{StaticResource ContextStyle}">
                        </MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem Header="Packs Columns"
                                 ItemsSource="{Binding PacksCollection}"
                                  DisplayMemberPath="Key"
Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.PacksCommand, 
                       RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
                                >
                        </MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem Header="Items Columns"
                       Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.ItemsCommand, 
                       RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
                       ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsCollection}" DisplayMemberPath="Key">
                        </MenuItem> 

                    </ContextMenu>
                </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
            </DataGrid>
        </Grid>
```

So, if you understand, i have a grid with Packs(Id,Number),each Pack have some Items(Id,Title). I want to have a context menu, which have 2 lists: Packs and Items. In each menu item we can choose what column to show.
ItemsCollection and PacksCollection are Dictionary where String - Column Header(same as in data grid) and bool - visibility state(true for Visible, false for Collapsed). 
Question: how to bind MVVM click on menu item, that will change column visibility. I tried some solutions, but they don't worked for me.
I need to change visibility for DataGrid columns(Id,Number) and for RowDetails DataGrid - Id, Title. Help please, i don't think this is so hard.
Thank you.